# Passing only index rather than UICollectionViewCell in delegate

Tags: swift

I have the custom `CollectionViewCell` and when a user clicks on a button which is located in the `collectionviewcell` then `delegate` method is getting called. It works, but I am passing `UICollectionViewCell` as a param. However, it is not efficient.

I would like to pass only selected customviewcell's **`index`** rather than entire Cell Object. How would you achieve that?

```
protocol CustomCollectionViewCellDelegate: AnyObject {
    func greenButtonTapped(cell: UICollectionViewCell)
}

class CustomCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    
    weak var delegate: CustomCollectionViewCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func greenButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.greenButtonTapped(cell: self)
    }
}
```

or something like that as a `closure` ?

```
var onTappingGreenButton: (UIButton, IndexPath) -> ()
```

Comment: Give the button an ID or something as `accessibilityIdentifier` through the view controller.

Comment: Get the index path from the table view with `indexPath(for:`

Comment: Could you please elaborate?